# How to copy indexes from one identical table to another existing identical table

Tags: mysql, indexing, copy, structure

I have 250 or so tables (mysql) that all share the exact same structure, except for indexes.  One of the tables has all the correct, current and up-to-date indexes, and I want to propagate that index structure to the other 249 tables.

Everything I've found searching is about copying a table with its content and index structure, which I don't want to do (the data in each table is different, only the structure is identical), or creating a NEW table with the same structure, which I also don't want to do.

I'm hoping there's a way to use ALTER TABLE to tell mysql to mimic the table structure of the correct table and apply that to the other table, optimize the table, and then run these commands through a php script to apply to all 249 tables, but I can't figure out if there's an ALTER TABLE command that will do this.

Any tips?

Comment: "I have 250 or so tables (mysql) that all share the exact same structure" ... Oh nooooooooooo!

Comment: No, there is no MySQL command to do this automatically, because this is not a situation anyone should ever be in.

Answer (score 5):

On the "good" table run `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table_name]`.  Copy the index lines and use those in a script to run the equivalent `ALTER TABLE CREATE INDEX` for every other table.

If you want the whole thing completely automated you'd have to parse the index definitions from a `SHOW INDEXES` or `SHOW CREATE TABLE` call.  But I'm assuming you just need to run this once since it's such an odd situation.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `CREATE TABLE LIKE` commands to create new tables that have the correct structure+indices but no data, and then `INSERT` statements to copy the old data over.

For example, suppose we have `users_master` as the table with the correct indices, and we want to give the correct indices to the table `users_n`.  We could do it like so:

```
CREATE TABLE users_n_indexed LIKE users_master;
INSERT users_n_indexed SELECT * FROM users_n;
DROP TABLE users_n;
RENAME TABLE users_n_indexed users_n;
```

of course create backups before you run any DROP statements.

Comment: Just to add a little on this answer, I will submit a new answer for people stumbling upon this.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer by Jeremy. Just in case your mysql complains,

```
CREATE TABLE users_n_indexed LIKE users_master;
INSERT users_n_indexed SELECT * FROM users_master;
DROP TABLE users_n;
RENAME TABLE users_n_indexed TO users_n;
```

You need to add a TO to the REMOVE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time creating something for this. My requirements changed at the end so I couldn't test it very well. But I believe this will work without much changes. I didn't like editing the output of "SHOW CREATE" - too dirty. So I went instead for the database fields created by "SHOW INDEX":

```
$res = mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW INDEX FROM tableA");
$indexes = array();
$nonuniques = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{ if(!isset($indexes[$row['Key_name']]))
    $indexes[$row['Key_name']] = array();
  $indexes[$row['Key_name']][] = $row['Column_name'];
  $nonuniques[$row['Key_name']] = $row['Non_unique'];
}
foreach($indexes AS $index => $fields)
{ $prefix = "";
  $indexname = "`".$index."`";
  if($index == "PRIMARY")
  { $indexname = "";
    $prefix = "PRIMARY";
  }
  else if($nonuniques[$index] == 0)
    $prefix = "UNIQUE";
  mysqli_query($conn,"ALTER TABLE tableB ADD ".$prefix." INDEX ".$indexname." ("`".implode("`,`", $fields)."`");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is old post, but I figured I could help someone else. You could do something like this:

```
SELECT concat("ALTER TABLE ",trim(TABLE_NAME)),group_concat(IF(INDEX_NAME="PRIMARY", 
"ADD PRIMARY KEY "," ADD INDEX `"),INDEX_NAME,"` (`",column_name,"` ASC) "), ";" 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA' and table_name like "TABLE_NAME%" 
and seq_in_index=1 group by table_name;`
```

or else for copy index to one table to others with same fields:

```
SELECT concat("ALTER TABLE ",trim(b.TABLE_NAME)),
group_concat(IF(a.INDEX_NAME="PRIMARY","ADD PRIMARY KEY "," ADD INDEX `"),
a.INDEX_NAME,"` (`",a.column_name,"` ASC) "), ";" FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS a 
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS b  WHERE a.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA' and  
a.table_name ="INDEX_TABLE" and b.table_name like "TABLES_TO_INDEX%" and 
a.seq_in_index=1 group by b.table_name;
```

then copy paste to query window.